# How to click on button with no text in Protractor ?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

[I want to Click on the two Plus(+) button but the button is not having any text in Music Library Section](http://angular.github.io/peepcode-tunes/public/)

How to Click the same?

I tried the following code:

```
describe ('angularjs homepage', function() {
    browser.get('http://angular.github.io/peepcode-tunes/public/');
    element(by.css('[ng-click="player.playlist.add(album)"]')).click();
});
```

Unfortunately It is not working.
Please Help

Comment: by saying "it is not working", you mean no action is fired or there are some errors in console? are you sure that your button has been found before clicking on it?

Comment: I have given Website Link. You can try and let me know. I am not able to locate the button . @tratto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better use protractor.ExpectedConditions to wait until element become clickable status and then do click operation.

Code Snippet:

```
EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

describe ('angularjs homepage', function() {

it('test case name',function(){

browser.ignoreSynchronization=true;

var twoButtons=element.all(by.css('.queue.add'));
browser.get('http://angular.github.io/peepcode-tunes/public/');

/*It will click first button, chance get(1) for second button*/    
browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(twoButtons.get(0)),  
                                          8000).thenCatch(function () {
                      assert.fail(' element is not click able');
              });
twoButtons.get(0).click();
});
});
```

Comment: Not Working @Suresh

Comment: Locator might be incorrect, Share you HTML code related to that button. and if not working attach your error message as well, that will help us to predict what might cause to issue

Comment: I have attached the website. Can you please see it with inspect element?

Comment: Tried . Not working. Can you run it on your end and let me know ?

Comment: @KishanPatel, seems to be that is not angularjs application. so i put **browser.ignoreSynchronization=true;**, now it will work. for me, it worked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117930/discussion-between-suresh-salloju-and-kishan-patel).

Comment: Hi suresh. I was able to click on + buttons. The problem is i want to click on all songs now. But all have same css path. What shouls i do ?

Comment: element.all(css locator which is same for all).each(function(ele,index){
ele.click();})

It will click all songs

Comment: element.all('.track.ng-scope.ng-binding').each(function(ele,index){ 
ele.click();


});

Wrote this.. Not working

Comment: element.all(by.css("[ng-repeat="track in album.tracks"]")).each(function(ele,index){
ele.click().then(function(){
browser.sleep(10000);});
});

Comment: Hey Suresh. Can you have a look at this question?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39284506/how-to-integrate-protractor-test-cases-in-atom-using-typescript

Answer (score 2):

You are not able to click them because both of them have same class & attributes. 
In these cases you have 2 options:

1) You can directly use `nth child` concept of CSS.

```
describe ('angularjs homepage', function() {
browser.get('http://angular.github.io/peepcode-tunes/public/');
element(by.css('#container > section > ul > li:nth-child(1) > button')).click();  // it will click the first "+" button
element(by.css('#container > section > ul > li:nth-child(2) > button')).click();  // it will click the second "+" button
});
```

2) You can access them with index as @noor suggested in the above answer:

```
describe ('angularjs homepage', function() {
browser.get('http://angular.github.io/peepcode-tunes/public/');
element.all(by.css('.queue.add')).get(0).click();  // it will click the first "+" button
element.all(by.css('.queue.add')).get(1).click();  // it will click the second "+" button
});
```

I tested it and both of them work! let me know if you face issues!

Comment: Failures:
1) angularjs homepage encountered a declaration exception
  Message:
    TypeError: element(...).get is not a function
  Stack:
    TypeError: element(...).get is not a function
        at Suite.<anonymous> (D:\Protractor\git.js:3:32)
        at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Protractor\git.js:1:1)
        at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
        at Module.require (module.js:367:17)

Comment: 1 spec, 1 failure
Finished in 0.03 seconds

C:\Users\kipatel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\pro
mise.js:1329
      return callbackFn(this.value_);
             ^
Error: Angular could not be found on the page http://angular.github.io/peepcode-tunes/public/ : angu
lar never provided resumeBootstrap
    at

Comment: I missed `.all` option , I updated my answer. did you try with `nth child`?

Comment: C:\Users\kipatel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\pr
mise.js:1329
      return callbackFn(this.value_);
             ^
Error: Angular could not be found on the page http://angular.github.io/peepcode-tunes/public/ : ang
lar never provided resumeBootstrap
    at C:\Users\kipatel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\protractor.js:679:17


Still i m getting this.. What wrong m i doing ? Can you test on your end and let me know?

Comment: which protractor version & jasmine framework r u using?

Comment: i checked them with `elementExplorer` jasmine2 and protractor 4.0.0 they work fine!

Comment: Protractor version is 3.2.0 and jasmine 2

Comment: I thinks you are using older version of Angular, there is as issue already resolved for this - https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3115. try upgrading to new protractor version 4.0.0 or 3.3.0. it would solve your issue. If you still have issue let's move this discussion to chat!

Comment: I upgrade everything. My error message was shorten just

No specs found
Finished in 0.002 seconds
[17:59:03] E/launcher - "process.on('uncaughtException'" error, see launcher
[17:59:03] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117925/discussion-between-igniteram1-and-kishan-patel).

Comment: Hey Ram .. Can you have a look at this ? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39284506/how-to-integrate-protractor-test-cases-in-atom-using-typescript

Comment: @RamPasala, can i have your skype id or contact number?

Comment: my skype id : igniteram

Answer (score 0):

i have checked this in java, though u don't tag java here. hope u can convert ur code to js.

in java,to click on first +, use the below:

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".queue.add")).get(0).click();
```

for second +:

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".queue.add")).get(1).click();
```

so, i think if u use the below code for js, this will work:

```
 element(by.css('.queue.add')).click();
```

if there is any way in js to take elements, first take elements and than click using element 
index.

Comment: noor , i've been working on selenium for past 1 year. I did the same in selenium. But i want it in protractor.  element(by.css('.queue.add')).click(); is not working, i tried it earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Protractor API](http://www.protractortest.org/) API. Make sure you have the latest version. You can grab the plus signs multiple ways. One way would be to use webdriver.By.css

Try :

```
browser.findElement(by.css('.queue')).click();
```

You can also add an ID to the plus sign and grab it that way, using webdriver.By.id