# How to integrate Protractor test cases in Atom using Typescript?

Tags: typescript, jasmine, protractor, atom-editor

I have installed typescript for atom for writing Protractor Scripts For automation.

My code is written in Jasmine Framework as protractor supports it nicely.

I wrote in this structure.

```
 describe('Sign in',function(){
     it ('Verify Modules Present', function(){
     loginPage.enterUsernameAndPasswordWithSignIn('a','b');
     browser.sleep(3000);
     var module = element(by.xpath("//*[@ng-reflect-router-link='My']"));
     browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(module),
                                  8000).thenCatch(function () {
              assert.fail(' element is not click able');
      });
    var expectedModuleName = ["My", "X","Y", "Z" ];
    var testArray = ["My", "X","Y", "Z" ];;
    logger.log('info','Checking All modules');
    for (var i = 0; i < testArray.length;i++) {
      var moduleName = text.verifyText("//*[@ng-reflect-router-link='"+ testArray[i] + "']");
      expect(moduleName).toBe(expectedModuleName[i]);
    }
  logger.log('info','Checked All modules');
  });
});
```

I am getting following errors.

[image: erros]

My understanding is : The Typescript is not able to find Jasmine libraries.
How to do so?

I went through:  https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/testing/jasmine-testing-101.html

But couldn't find much. I installed typings too. But I don't know how to use it.

How can i configure Jasmine Framework into atom for Protractor so that this errors may resolve?

If not so, Which editor can be useful to do so and how?

Please guide me..

Comment: add below two lines at the top of your spec even include /// as well - 


/// <reference path="DefinitelyTyped/requirejs/require.d.ts" />
import bb = require('backbone');

Comment: Can you please elaborate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to install `jasmine` and `node` typings so that typescript recognizes them. Now there is even a better approach, there is no need of typings folder and typings.json. we have `@types` dependencies for the same.

so you can do that by following steps-

go to your project folder and install the dependencies -

```
 npm install --save-dev @types/jasmine //this would install jasmine typings as a dev dependency in your package.json
 npm install --save-dev @types/node   //this would install node typings as a dev dependency in your package.json
```

once you have installed try compiling it with `tsc` or `tsc -w` watch mode, now you shouldn't see those TS syntax errors!

And you have to import `browser` from `protractor/globals` to use its methods, like this-

```
import {browser} from 'protractor/globals';
```

For more details you can check out my rep for initial setup of [protractor with typescript](https://github.com/igniteram/protractor-cucumber-typescript) it uses cucumber as well as you can check out the official [protractor-typescript example](https://github.com/angular/protractor/tree/master/exampleTypescript)

Comment: I'm not getting you bro..  npm install --save-dev @types/node failed.
Can we have chat ?

Comment: Can I get all my stuffs ready , for visual studio code? Writing Protractor test scripts in Typescripts using Jasmine Framework ?

Comment: I tried installing both. I got @Types folder under which there was jasmine and node folder.

The browser is imported correctly using import {browser} from 'protractor/globals';


But describe, it, expect are still showing errors. Please help

Comment: did you try compiling with `tsc`? it should work! there are some glitches where it shows errors in editor but it compiles actually , typescript folks are working on it. meanwhile give it a try!

Comment: also make sure you are using latest `Typscript 2.0`

Comment: Yes i have Typescript 2.0

Comment: My application is going from standalone to web. Now i have to write test case for automation in protractor using typescript in visual studio code. What should be my approach?

Comment: Ram can you please help ?

Comment: I have answered it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39348479/how-to-write-protractor-test-scripts-using-typescript-along-with-jasmine-framewo/39384579#39384579)

Comment: Ram Pasala, I was trying to install protractor dependencies on my friend machines. But global.js and typings folder didnt install. Why so ? Is there any specific thing i need to install ?

Comment: Hi Ram Pasala.. Can we have a discussion. I am stuck badly.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, some of these issues (require and loginPage, for example) aren't necessarily anything to do with Jasmine. However, the issue is that these are global variables and the TS compiler can't find their declaration. The easiest way to remedy this is to declare each one at the top of the file in the following way:

`declare var describe: any;`

This will resolve the issues with `describe` and `it`. Other problems, such as `require` will be because you're not using the [module import syntax](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html).

Answer (score 0):

This didn't quite fix the problem for me. In addition to installing the jasmine types (above answer)

I had to open `tsconfig.json` and insure `jasmine` was in the list of `types` under `compilerOptions`. For example

`{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "paths": {
      "environments": [
        "./environments"
      ]
    },
    "types": [
      "node",
      "jasmine"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}`

After adding `"jasmine"` as a type, the errors disappeared in Atom immediately.