# how to get float value from element?

Tags: html, xpath, protractor, gettext

I can't find answer to my problem. I need to get value 0.01 from below and then operate with it, eg. add some value etc.

Let's say we have an HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>Exchange rate</div>
        <span>0.01</span>
    </body>
</html>
```

So the xpath is

```
„//div[text() = ‘Exchange rate’]/../span”
```

In protractor I manage to create element variable:

```
var element = element(by.xpath(„//div[text() = ‘Exchange rate’]/../span”));
```

Now I need to get float value from it and use it later in code.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start with, your html is non-angular and using 'element' will throw you errors. I am not sure if the code snippet is just an example and if you are actually operating on angular pages, so I will answer both cases

For Non-Angular case:

`browser.driver.get("<<>>/test.html");
        browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath('//span')).getText().then(function(value){
            console.log("The Float value is " + parseFloat(value))
        });`

For Angular pages:

```
    browser.get("<<>>/test.html");
    element(by.xpath('//span')).getText().then(function(value){
        console.log("The Float value is " + parseFloat(value))
    });
```

Comment: It is worth to mention that outside code you created we cannot use parseFloat(value). I mean even if we declare a variable just before your code and assign parseFloat(value) to it, we cannot use it outside. I wonder why. I am new with protractor and JS.

Comment: the content of getText - value is returned back in the promise and the scope of it is only within the callback function of following then. And in case you are declaring variables outside the webdriverJs control flow, they run async and don't wait for webdriver commands to finish. Please refer this - https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md

Comment: Aditya !!! Can you help me on this..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39284506/how-to-integrate-protractor-test-cases-in-atom-using-typescript




http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39348479/how-to-write-protractor-test-scripts-using-typescript-along-with-jasmine-framewo?noredirect=1#comment66036450_39348479

Comment: Sure ... Will check on it but I am no expert on typescript :(